# Sorting lists, not the output I want

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I'm sorting a list of names from a list. I want to sort the names in a way so the names get printed out on different lines, not the whole list, eg for-loop?

Like so;

```
Abc
Bcd
Cde
Def
```

Not `['Abc', 'Bcd', 'Cde', 'Def']`

But this sorts all the letters in each name, not the elements of names:

```
for names in nameslist:
  names = sorted(names)
  print(names)
```

What is the correct way to do it? sort() does not work (`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the sorting how to over here:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

As for your case. I think this would do the trick for you:

```
for name in sorted(namelist): 
    print( name )
```

Comment: Nothing to it @saltcracker

Answer (score 2):

You can join the names with a new line character :

```
print('\n'.join(names))
```

Comment: Thank you! This would be the whole list, just seperating each name on a different line?

Comment: @saltcracker Yes, you can simply give it a try ;)